# 2D array of pointers C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

This may be fairly easy to answer but i cant seem to figure out the syntax for it. What i need is a 2D array the first element would be pointers to CSTRING's and the second element would be a counter.

The purpose of this is for threading and passing word lists to threads based on the thread number. As in if it was defined something like char wordlists[100][10] (100 words and 10 lists 1 for each thread 10 total) i could initially fill all the lists up with words from a file and then pass a specific list to a thread to process and once a thread joins back to the main thread i would refill the word list related to the joining thread and relaunch the thread with new words.

Overall i dont get the syntax for making a 2D array of pointers (first element pointers second just a counter). Also is it possible to pass just the array address where the words for the particular thread starts at so i dont need to pass the entire 2D array of 1000 words? (so that i can just pass the starting address where that threads 100 words are stored)

thanks for the help!

edit:: if you guys have any better suggestions for a similar way to process big word files via threads then do suggest them im open to more ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to partition the array across your threads? The original table definition would probably help in your question, as I don't think this is going to be as complicated as you first think.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i am trying to create 10 lists of 100 words and give 1 list to each thread and upon their joining with the main thread refill their list and relaunch them until the word file is completely read through.

Comment: Ok. Is the *source* of what you're trying to split up and send to your threads coming from a larger (and more importantly, **complete**) list?

Comment: I stopped at the first paragraph. If you need a CString and a counter, use a struct.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes the main list is a file located on the harddrive consisting of 300, 000 or more words based on the file i pick.

Comment: Ok. if that is the case, you probably don't need anything elaborate, especially if the file is already loaded in memory in you string list. Only two more questions: Can you post the *declaration* (code not needed beyond that) of the master array of words read from the source file up in your question? And finally, you mentioned a CString. Is this C++ using either MFC or ATL, or by CString did you mean a traditional `char*` zero-terminated C string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i dont get the syntax for making a 2D array of pointers

`*` has a lower precedence than `[]`. Therefore wordlists is an array of array of pointer to `char`.

```
char *wordlists[100][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a 2D array of pointers (to type `T`):

```
T *array[width][height];
```

> Also is it possible to pass just the array address [...] so I don't need to pass the entire 2D array of 1000 words?

You couldn't even do anything else. In C, arrays are always passed by pointer, not by value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can benefit from reading the (relevant parts of, but i'd recommend the WHOLE of) the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

It is probably a mandatory read for anyone touching C (and C-like langages), and it is incredibly eye-opening (especially about undefined statements behavior, null pointers value and use, and, in your case, pointers and arrays of pointers).